# REST Creating a resource at point-of-request

Tags: rest, http-headers, http-verbs, idempotent

Say I have the need to expose a service, where I can request an analysis of a user over a specific range of time (common actions, activities, relationships, etc.).
I would immediately think of this as:

```
/users/{userId}/analyses - POST
/users/{userId}/analyses/{analysisId} - GET
```

The problem here, is where the 'analysis' resource comes into existence - it is inherently request-based as it is the service that will do this complex analysis, and also the service that has the most up-to-date state of the user data. In short, it doesn't exist prior to request.

My current thinking has me at three options for requesting an analysis for the first time (with retrieval being the same):

```
/users/{userId}/analyses?from=2017-01-01&to=2018-01-01 - GET
/users/{userId}/analyses - POST { "from": "2017-01-01", "to": "2018-01-01" }
/users/{userId}/analyses?from=2017-01-01&to=2018-01-01 - POST
```

I like the GET with query parameters, as I'm requesting a resource, and scoping the user data to be used, until I recognise that the resource could change between requests (based on data on the back end, or processing logic change), and that I would need to call a second time to POST this resource.

I like the POST with the request body, as I'm expecting a resource to be created, until I recognise that the state I've transferred, is not the state I would get back when I retrieve this later, nor is it even the same hypermedia type.

I like the POST with query parameters and no body, as I'm creating a resource and scoping that resource, but I'm still transferring a state that isn't the resource or end media type, and I've seen practically no other examples of POSTs with query parameters.

Anyone have experience with these kinds of actions in a RESTful manner?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using `GET /users/{userId}/analyses?from=...&to=...` is a good approach.

You request a resource of type `analysis` which means you have to use HTTP verb `GET`. You pass parameters to limit the scope. That the resource might change between two requests is not a problem. You request a resource in a specific state and this state might be changed right after your `GET` request. Compare this to a collection resource where other clients are allowed to `POST` something.

Using `POST` would imply that you want clients to create a resource of type `analysis` with all necessary data, which is from what I understand not true in your case. Your own counter-arguments for the second and third example are correct, in my opinion.